# Can you tap three colored-mana-producing lands to produce one mana of any color?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I don't recall where I first heard of this being a thing, whether it just being from a friend mentioning it or reading it off of some random website. Regardless, my friend group and I have been playing with this rule for a good while now, though none of us can remember where we first heard of it, and we can't find any information about speculation of this online anywhere.

I know technically tapping a land produces one mana of the color on it (assuming it's your normal land that only produces one mana upon being tapped, such as a basic land), so technically it would be more accurate to ask if three colored mana can be swapped out with one mana of any color. If this is a thing, do the three mana need to all be one color, or can they be of any color, or even colorless? If this isn't, then I can only wonder as to where I first heard of this rule (though I guess nothing is stopping the rule being homebrewed in during casual play).

Comment: It's definitely an obscure house rule, nothing official like that ever existed. It does sound a lot like Settler of Catan's 3:1 trading port.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, this is not a rule. I don't think there is a succinct way to provide a quote to prove it, other than "Read the entire rule set and see that it's not there".

But as you say, there is nothing stopping you from using that rule in casual play.

Comment: There are, however, cards such as Prismite that give you the ability to turn any 2 mana to 1 mana of any color.